# Splitting matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

The result of below computation :

```
weights = np.array([[1,2] , [3,4]])
X = np.array([[1,1,1] , [2,2,2]])
p(weights)
p(X)
np.dot(weights , X)
```

is :

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
[[1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]]
Out[215]:
array([[ 5,  5,  5],
       [11, 11, 11]])
```

How to compute the vector values `[ 5,  5,  5]` & `[11, 11, 11]` individually instead of computing within one matrix dot product ?

I'm not sure if this is possible. I've tried just accessing single X value but returns error  :

```
weights = np.array([[1,2] , [3,4]])
X = np.array([[1,1,1] , [2,2,2]])
p(weights)
p(X)
np.dot(weights , X[0])

[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
[[1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-216-e2b82527526d> in <module>()
      3 p(weights)
      4 p(X)
----> 5 np.dot(weights , X[0])

ValueError: shapes (2,2) and (3,) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)
```

Update :

I'm attempting to compute  `[ 5,  5,  5]` or `[11, 11, 11]` but not both, is this possible ?

Update 2 :

Is this possible by modifying the X value and leaving weights as is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

weights = np.array([[1,2] , [3,4]])
X = np.array([[1,1,1] , [2,2,2]])
for row_vec in weights:
    print(np.dot(row_vec , X))
```

Which prints:

```
[5 5 5]
[11 11 11]
```

---

EDIT

> "I'm attempting to compute [ 5,  5,  5] or [11, 11, 11] but not both, is this possible ?"

If you just want to compute **any** of them, just go with slicing:

for example:

```
print(np.dot(weights[0] , X))  # -> [5 5 5]
```

or

```
print(np.dot(weights[1] , X))  # -> [11 11 11]
```

Comment: thanks, please see my question update, hope this clarifies.

Comment: @blue-sky but which one? Anyone?

Comment: Please see further question update. Apologies about not providing such detail initially. Perhaps i should accept your answer and open a new question.

Comment: @blue-sky Is this an interview for a job that adaptively gets harder the better I do?

Comment: again, I apologies, will accept, thanks for your help.